# Create a personalised page for an element

Tags: go

I'm not sure if the caption is correct so you are very welcome to suggest another one.

Basically, I have a small web-service which is a catalogue of courses. The catalogue page is displayed correctly but I cannot make a course-page work correctly.

Here is my handler for the course page:

```
func courseHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "course", courses)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

Here is how I parse templates and store courses:

```
var courses map[string]*models.Course

var templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
```

I also have templates for catalogue and course pages where I put the values in {{...}} format.

Here is an example of a course element in a catalogue HTML page which is a link to a course page.

```
{{ range $key, $value := . }}
    <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <div
          class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
          <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
            <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-success">{{ $value.Category }}</strong>
            <h3 class="mb-0">{{ $value.Title }}</h3>
            <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ $value.StartDate }}</div>
            <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{ $value.Description }}</p>
            <a href="/course?id={{$key}}" class="stretched-link">Узнать больше</a>
          </div>
          <img class="float-right" width="200" height="250" src="{{$value.Image}}">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{ end }}
```

I also register my handlers using martini framework:

```
staticOptions := martini.StaticOptions{Prefix: "templates"}
    m.Use(martini.Static("templates", staticOptions))
    m.Get("/", indexHandler)
    m.Get("/add", addHandler)
    m.Get("/courses", coursesHandler)
    m.Get("/edit", editHandler)
    m.Get("/delete", deleteHandler)
    m.Post("/SaveCourse", saveCourseHandler)
    m.Post("/course", courseHandler
```

When I try to proceed to the course page I get a "404 Not Found" error.

Comment: It is unlikely that your problem is related to your templates. It is more likely that your handler is registered for a different path than you're trying, or it is not registered at all. That is, you're either looking at the wrong url, or there is no handler for the courses url.

Comment: @bserdar I registered my handlers and the path seems to be correct, I also provided the code

Comment: You registered POST /course, but with href, it'll do a GET /course

Comment: @bserdar thank you!